# How to specify PHP MYSQL dates without time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This works perfectly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers 
FROM customertable 
WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '2016-06-28 10:27:55' AND '2016-07-05 14:07:51';
```

However, since I'm using javascript datepicker for the user to pick the date periods and have only dates but no times this apparently does not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers 
FROM customertable 
WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '2016-06-28' AND '2016-07-05';
```

My select statement is this: $t1 is lower date while $t2 is upper date.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT customertable FROM customer WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '$t1' AND '$t2'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Is there a way I can insert a concatenated date, say '$t1'.12.00.00, on my select statement to take care of the full DATETIME entry on my database when selecting?

Comment: (1) How does it not work?  The date formats are fine.  (2) Why aren't you using parameterized queries?  You shouldn't be embedding parameter values in the query string.

Comment: A user should use javascript date picker calendar to select date intervals. However, the date picker has only date of the months and no time. Works with date and time but not with dates only

Comment: Are you sure the date picker is returning date in format `YYYY-MM-DD` ?

Comment: just make sure that `$t1` and `$t2` are supplied with the correct format from that JS side, and as Gordon  have said, you should have used prepared statements instead

Comment: `WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '$t1 00:00:00' AND '$t2 00:00:00'` should work just fine. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Never, ever, ever use string interpolation into a SQL statement.  That's how SQL injection attacks happen.  Use placeholders instead.
2. Modify the format generated by the javascript date picker to include a time.

and/or

3. Add a time component to the date strings if they come in without one.

Answer (score -2):

In case of date without time values in query.

You can divide datetime value by space and check if it has time or not.

If it has no time param so just add 00:00:00 and 23:59:59.

See this example:

```
function getCustomers($from, $to) {
  $from = explode(' ', $from);
  if(sizeof($from) != 2) {
    $from = $from[0]. ' 00:00:00';
  }

  $to = explode(' ', $to);
  if(sizeof($to) != 2) {
    $to = $to[0]. ' 23:59:59';
  }

   // re-parsing datetime values to prevent sql injection 
  $from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($from));
  $to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($to));

  $q =   
    "SELECT DISTINCT customers 
    FROM customertable 
    WHERE time_paid >= '".$from."' AND time_paid <= '".$to."'";

  // and so on...  
}
```